# Unity3D - Button Only Works Once?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is super strange. This simple button is not clickable at all. But when I close the Unity and Mono editors and fire it up again, it will work - only once. I mean, the second time you hit the play button, the button will not work anymore. I didn't change settings of the button or the canvas. I just put them in the scene and click play button. I think this is a bug? But there's no log i can see. This is bugging me for good 30 mins. I even restarted my PC and still working only on the first hit of play button. Thanks

EDIT: just found the problem. This problem occurs when you use the Unity Remote app on Android. It will work first. But when you try it the second time, buttons are not responding anymore. The only solution I found for this is to reinstall the Unity. Tried restarting PC but didn't work. Soo, peace out. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your button settings in inspector?

Comment: Also, how are you determining the button isn't clicking?  The UI isn't playing the click effect animation or do you have a console log message that's only firing once?

Comment: Do you have "Collapse" enabled in your Console window? That's gotten me a few times

Comment: Are you getting an error on the Console?

Comment: can you show us relevant code please? what exactly is "button is not clickable at all"? what are you expecting to happen when it clicks?

Comment: NevenIgnjic i didnt change anything in the button settings the moment i add it.

slumtrimpet yes, the UI is not playing the UI hover and clicked animation

VenkatatAxiomStudios no errors or logs found in the console

@Andrew its not responding to any action even animation

I got it working anyway, guys, I just updated it 5.1.3 (previous is 5.1.1 the version i had a problem)

Thank you guys for support! :)

Comment: I also has the same error. Really strange. (Mine was 5.3.1 version of Unity) Now installing the 5.3.3 version. Hope no error on this one

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on the `Force Module Active` property on inspector in EventSystem. I had the same problem on Version 5.3.1 on my machine (macbook pro mid 2010 on OSX El Capitan). Deleted the Unity, rolled back to 5.2.2, upgrade to 5.3.3, the problem is still there. Did that and somehow it works, but I don't know the reason why

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. But I've proved that the problem was the Unity Remote when you're trying to debug thru your Android phone and not the w/n the Unity editor.